# C++ - weird thread behavior when pass vector to method

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, stdthread

I wrote the following code and noticed a weird behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

void withVectorArg(double waitTime, std::vector<int> q = {}) {
    std::cout << "[withVectorArg] waitTime: " << waitTime << "s" << '\n';
    std::thread thread([&waitTime]() {
        std::cout << "[withVectorArg] waitTime: " << waitTime << "s" << '\n';
    });
    thread.detach();
}

void withoutVectorArg(double waitTime) {
    std::cout << "[withoutVectorArg] waitTime: " << waitTime << "s" << '\n';
    std::thread thread([&waitTime]() {
        std::cout << "[withoutVectorArg] waitTime: " << waitTime << "s" << '\n';
    });
    thread.detach();
}

int main() {
    withVectorArg(1);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    withoutVectorArg(1);
    while (true) {}
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
[withVectorArg] waitTime: 1s
[withVectorArg] waitTime: 3.38411e-312s
[withoutVectorArg] waitTime: 1s
[withoutVectorArg] waitTime: 1s
```

Both methods do exactly the same and do not use the `q` variable, yet the first one somehow changes the value of `waitTime`.

Does someone know why this happens?

Thank you!

Comment: As the tag suggests, undefined behavior like accessing a dangling reference is undefined. All kinds of apparently innocuous changes can alter the observed behavior of the program.

Comment: The lambda captures `waitTime` by reference to a local variable.  The thread might be scheduled after the function that started it has exited.

Comment: @NathanPierson So what are you suggesting? Never pass by reference?

Comment: If you are detaching the thread you need to ensure that any capture by reference parameters outlive the lifetime of the thread.

Comment: References can dangle in buggy code.  That doesn't mean "never pass by reference", it means "using references requires you to ensure the lifetime of the object referenced".  In your case, you are giving a thread a reference to `waitTime`, an object that ceases to exist as soon as the function is exited.

Comment: Using references with threads adds complexity. If the complexity outweighs the advantages the reference brings, and it sure does in this case, lose the reference.

Comment: `while (true) {}` is undefined behaviour. Don't do this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to test here because the only wait is done at the main thread, but you can just launch threads in parallel and make each of them them wait for a given time this other way (for example), without any detach: https://godbolt.org/z/GMGd5q457

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your functions are undefined behavior.

The reason is that you're starting a thread, detaching it and exiting the function immediately. The thread however is capturing the parameter BY REFERENCE and thus when the code in the thread body is executed (that MAY happen AFTER you already returned from the function) the local variable that the reference is bound to does not exist any more (that local was destroyed when returning from the function).

What happens when you enter the UB realm is simply undefined, trying to explain the exact weird behavior is a waste of time.

Comment: ...Unless you're a security researcher or malicious individual seeking to exploit it.